# Is a non-compete clause enforceable if competition is in another market

Tags: united-kingdom, different-countries

I've signed a 2 year non-compete clause with a UK-based company (in e-commerce) that says I "may not be involved in any capacity with a business which does or could compete with the Company" about a year ago and I'm planning to move to Japan to start a similar business.

Considering my business would not actually compete with their business as they only operate in Europe and I'd solely operate in Japan, would the non-compete clause still be enforceable?

I know it wouldn't make much sense to sue me (which does cost money) to nail me for something that's not actually damaging them. But I wonder if they could legally sue me?

Comment: Are you talking about a non-complete or a non-disclosure agreement (NDA)?

Comment: Non-compete, sorry! Updated it now...

Comment: I would expect a non-complete for a domestic company is not enforceable internationally, but I'm not a lawyer so don't quote me on that.

Comment: Hire a lawyer given your personal ties to the new company.  The vail of an LLC or similar can be broken.

Comment: That is such a wide non compete I doubt that it would be enforceable in the UK - you where paid for this non compete.

Comment: Another thing would probably be, that by the time you get well settled in Japan and get your business up and running, the 2 years may have passed.

Comment: @AsheraH do you mean that they'd have to sue me before the end of the 2 years?

Comment: @user40242 I'm not sure on the need to actually sue you before the end of the 2 years, but to actually start a lawsuit, they have to have incurred enough damages in that time to make it worth their while. Since you signed it already a year ago and it will probably take some time to make the move, start your business and grow to be enough of a threat to them, from a separate market, that chance is pretty small.

Comment: I agree with Neuromancer - non-competes are usually non enforceable in the UK, which makes them worth only as much as the ink they're printed on. See [this article on Business Advise](https://businessadvice.co.uk/insurance/liability-and-indemnity/when-are-non-compete-clauses-enforceable/) on the subject.

Comment: Whether it's enforceable or not, people shouldn't sign such a non-compete agreement. The employer obviously believes it can be used at least as a threat, and that's something you want to avoid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tld;dr. You almost certainly have nothing to worry about.

I am not a lawyer, so check with https://law.stackexchange.com/

However, a few decades back, I did study business law in the UK and we looked at non-compete clauses.

These originate in the middle ages in the UK (they probably had them back in ancient Rome & Greece). The problem that the were intended to solve was that of apprenticeship. A youth would spend seven years learning a trade from his master, who didn't want him to take that seven years training and set himself up in direct competition.

Imagine a shoemaker in a small town. Imagine he has an apprentice. And imagine the town is too small to support two shoemakers.

Now you see the necessity of the non-complete clause.

However, the law is not one-sided, and realises that the apprentice had to earn a living, and that there was only one way for him to do so - in the trade which he had just learned.

So, no-compete clauses were deemed to be unreasonable (thus unenforceable) if they were too restrictive in either distance or time.

If the shoemaker said that the apprentice could not set up a rival business in the next 20 years, that sounds unreasonable, whereas six months might be reasonable.

Similarly, he might forbid him from starting a competing business within a 10 mile radius, but not 200 miles.

Alas, when I studied law, there was no such thing as e-commerce, where the distance factor might be irrelevant. However, since you say

> my business would not actually compete with their business as they only operate in Europe and I'd solely operate in Japan

I am confident that there would be no problem at all. You might consider asking them. They will probably be reluctant, but if they won't say there is no problem, then a quick chat with a lawyer will clear your worries.

Most lawyers give an hour's initial consultation free, and you will probably find one who tells you for free that you are in the clear, but who will charge a fee for a letter saying so, which you could show your present employer if necessary.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was gonna write, but with a local bakery as an example. Worth adding that the limitation on type of business is not just for exactly the same, in the case of the shoemaker, a no-compete clause on any leatherworking might be enforceable.

Comment: Good point (+1). Part of me wishes I had stayed with business law, but I took one semester of the new computer thingie that was just coming out & got hooked :-)